# Google Calendar Data API v3 PHP Key Problems

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I've been working on updating my [FRC](http://www.usfirst.org/roboticsprograms/frc) team's [website](http://www.team1294.org/) from Google Calendar Data API v1 to v3. I have the actual code for the Google API PHP Client working, and I have the ability to get data, but I 'm having trouble with using an API key set for a specific referer.

In the Google Developers Console I have a key for the referers:

`http://localhost/
*.team1294.org/*`

, but when I try to use it I get `(403) Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions.` Is there something wrong with the way my key is setup? How would I fix this?

Comment: Try `www.team.org` or `*.team1294.org` (if you want to exclude team1294.org)

Comment: @Andy My goal is to be able to have a key that can work on `localhost` and `team1294.org`, but with the way my key is set up, it doesn't seem to work. I was just wondering if there is a way to fix this, but it's fine because this key isn't actually going to be used in production.